# iOS fast send to address Email?

Tags: ios, iphone

Exist method create link fast call to number: **(phone number).tel.QLNK.net** in iPhone’s Safari.

Maybe there is a way to send an email to a specified address quickly?

Comment: Can you reformulate your question clearly?

Comment: @Epexa if your question isn't for a URL API, then how is it about programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a `mailto:` URL, specifying the destination: `mailto:mail@example.com`.

This will open the iOS mail app and compose a message to that address. You can add other fields, like subject, to the URL, with standard GET argument syntax, e.g. `mailto:mail@example.com?subject=hello`.

Comment: not programmer version, please user version.
create web short link "mailto:mail@example.com" ?

Comment: @Epexa it's a normal URL, you can do whatever you want with it. I updated my answer with an HTML example instead, but you can put it wherever you want.

Comment: you not understand my question!
need short link in my iphone, no web page!
please see analog fast call method: (phone number).tel.QLNK.net

Comment: @Epexa try typing `mailto:mail@example.com` into Safari. It'll make an email to that address.